# How do I change column values in pandas if it contains a part of string which I want to replace?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I'm cleaning form results in a survey.

Under the column named 'Which source do you trust the most to get insights on politics?' all entries which contain row entry with string/substring 'news' should be replaced with the string 'newspapers or news apps'

Here, 'responses' is the name of the csv file of survey responses.

```
if responses['Which source do you trust the most to get insights on politics?'].str.contains('news') == True:
    responses['Which source do you trust the most to get insights on politics?'] = 'newspapers or news apps'
```

I got the following error for the code:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

please help! any leads appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick will be to create a boolean index with the `.str.contains("news")` then use `.loc` to update your original dataframe and overwrite those specific values. The following code should do the trick:

```
source_colname = 'Which source do you trust the most to get insights on politics?'
contains_news = responses[source_colname].str.contains('news')

responses.loc[contains_news, source_colname] = "newspapers or news app"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Colname = 'Which source do you trust the most to get insights on politics?' 
responses.loc[responses[Colname].str.contains('news'), Colname]= 'newspapers or news apps'
```